# Git repositories sync

Tags: git, ssh, git-bare

How can I keep two git repository synced?

The first repository is a "central" repository used by the team to push changes, created following [the git book guide](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).
The second repository will be only a *mirror* of the first.

I'm using git with ssh and changes should be pushed only from the first repository since it is behind a secured network.

Comment: git does not push empty directories. put some file called like (e.g. .empty) in it

Comment: how can the first repo be a bare repo if you are making changes to it? I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: @pcantalupo I'm fixed the question, since I was confused about the --bare command used to create it.

Comment: @AlexisPeters The common convention is to put an empty file called `.gitkeep` in otherwise empty directories that you'd like Git to keep around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first repository knows about its mirror, you can use a [`post-receive`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook. According to the manual, one of the common uses of such a hook is to notify others of a successfully received update.

To create such a hook, put a script (any script, the language/interpreter is determined by the shebang at the top) named `post-receive` in your `hooks` folder under `.git` (or under the main repo if it is bare). In the hook, run a command to push to the remote you are interested in. A sample script could be as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
git push mirror
```

Here, `mirror` is the name of the mirror remote as configured in the main repository.